# Creating an efficient synthetic route to this elastomeric block copolymer

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, polymers

[image: Elastomeric block copolymer]

This was a question my professor gave me in which I have a couple of ideas to create a synthetic route which include: Either an anionic or cationic polymerization? If so, I don't think it would be cationic because I can't seem to see if there would be some sort of initiator system and i don't think there could be carbocation formation either from the looks of it. The only feasible conclusion I have come to is that it would be an **anionic polymerization** where you create a **living polymer** and react this with a **second** monomer to create a block copolymer? I could maybe use an organolithium to start the initation with a polar solvent however I don't actually know which monomer to start off with nor how the reaction mechanism would work out. Can someone help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: Should the copolymer units have m,n type subscripts as opposed to being of a specific ratio?

Comment: _sigh_ It's polyaddition. You don't need any catalyst.

Answer (score 1):

How about starting with a difunctional isocyanate, adding hydrazine in step 1 and polyethylene glycol in step 2. I would call it an addition polymerization. Your structure does not show the number of repeating units, but that could be largely controlled by varying the monomer proportions.